# Switching to other versions of PyCharm unsets the Project Interpreter in the previous one

Tags: windows-7, python, pycharm

I have installed both PyCharm Edu 2018.3 and PyCharm Professional 2018.1.5 in my computer. Every time I switch from Edu to Professional and vice versa, I have to set the Project Interpreter, because it's lost.

---

The detailed description (TL;DR):

I open some project *in one of these versions of PyCharm*, and all is OK.

Then I open the same project *in the other one* - to find that the Project Interpreter *is not set* - in spite that *I set it before* (to the path `C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\python.exe`). So I set it to the same path again, and all things work.

But this time *only in this version of PyCharm.*

Because when I switch back to the *previous version* of Pycharm, the situation is similar - I find that the Project Interpreter is not set - in spite that all things worked before, and the Project Interpreter *was set* (to the same path `C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\python.exe`).

So I set it to the same path again, and all things work now - but only in this version of Pycharm, because after switching back to the other version, the Project Interpreter is not set.

It doesn't matter when I switch between active versions of PyCharm, or when I exit one version, and then I launch the other one.

**One version of PyCharm unset Project Interpreter in the other one, and vice versa.**

What happens, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuration parameters are saved in *2 different places:*

[image: 2 Configuration Places]

You have installed 2 version of PyCharm - Edu and Professional - so you have *3 configuration places:*

[image: 3 Configuration Places]

Every version of PyCharm has *its own list of available interpreters,* for example:

[image: Lists of Interpreters]
Note that the Project Interpreter is (so far) not set, and that every interpreter has its **name**.

Now we open our project in Pycharm Edu, and select a Project Interpreter for it:

[image: Select an Interpreter]
Note that in the Project Configuration, the selected interpreter is saved as its **name**, and NOT as the *interpreter itself (a path to it).*

Now we open the same project in PyCharm Professional (or switch to it, if it was already opened):

[image: No Such Name]

We may see, that the name of its Project Interpreter (`Name1`) *is NOT found* in the PyCharm Professional list of its interpreters. And as the result of  it, *you have NOT set the Project Interpreter for PyCharm professional!*

So you are forced to select one - and you select the *same* interpreter, but now with the name `NameA`. All is OK, while you don't switch to PyCharm Edu, after that you will meet the same problems.

The solution is to **assign the same names for the same interpreters** in both version of Pycharm (Edu and Professional):
[image: Now it is OK]

That's all. Now you can freely switch between 2 versions of PyCharm, and nothing bad happens.

---

***How that problem may arise?***

1. Because the *original names* of interpreters were *long and very, very similar. Compare the following names:*

   `Python 3.6 (C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\python.exe)`
     `Python 3.6.1 (C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\python.exe)`
2. Because as part of that names was the *full path to the corresponding interpreter,* so the user was *misguided* - they supposed that they selected an *interpreter*, while they selected a ***name***.

***Who assigned those*** **long names,** ***and why to*** **the same path** ***were chosen*** **different names** ***in different versions of PyCharm (Edu and Professional)?***

The PyCharm itself. In the time of its installation (or just after it) it *searches* local disk(s) for Python Interpreters, *adds* each one into its list, and *assigns it a **name** composed of*

- the interpreter's *name*,
- the interpreter's *version number*, and
- the *full path to it* (in parentheses).

If between installations of two PyCharm versions the user *updates a particular interpreter*, its *new version number* becomes the *part of its new name*, so it will *differ from the name used in the Python Interpreter list of the first PyCharm version*.

And the problems listed in the question will arise...

---

***How to change the name of an interpreter?***

From the Project Interpreter.

It's a little counter-intuitive, because the list of interpreters (with their names) *has nothing with the project configuration* - it's a part of a particular *PyCharm edition configuration.*

```
File | Settings... | Project: (your_project_name) | Project Interpreter
```

Then click on Project Interpreter combo-box (1), and select "Show all..." (2).

Pops-up a window with a misleading, deceptive name "Project Interpreters" in its title. It's not true, as it lists NOT *project* interpreters, but *Pycharm (this particular version)* interpreters!

Select the interpreter with the unsatisfactory name, click on icon with a pencil on it (3) to edit it, and in another popup window rewrite the name of that interpreter (4):

[image]